# checking if directory empty in NodeJs and switching returns in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to check if a directory that i'm storing images inside is empty or not (because i don't want it to contain more than one image) , however the code isn't working it let's me store multiple files

what i'm trying to do is upload an image and store it then directy display it,

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
const cors= require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(cors());
const fileName="map" // static file name
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination :(req,file,cb)=>{
    cb(null,'upload/heat-map'); //second param is destination of storage
  },
  filename: (req,file,cb)=>{
    console.log(file);
    cb(null,fileName+path.extname(file.originalname));//naming the file with the callback function
  }
})
const upload = multer({  storage : storage }); // Set the destination folder for uploaded files
const port = 8000;
```

this is the function that is making me troubles

```
const isDirectoryEmpty = (directoryPath) => {
  try {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath);
    return files.length === 0;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error reading directory:', error);
    return false; // Handle the error as per your requirement
  }
};
```

```
const directoryPath = 'upload/heat-map';

if(isDirectoryEmpty(directoryPath)){ // checking if the path of the image is empty (trying to prevent //mutiple upload
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.file) {
      
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No file uploaded' });
    }else{
      res.send("Image uploaded");
    }});
}else{
try{
app.use('map', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'upload','heat-map')));
}catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}  
app.get('/getMap', async (req,res)=>{ 
  //const imgPath="http://localhost:8000/heat-map_back/upload/heat-map/.png"
  try{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'upload/heat-map/', 'map.png'));
  res.status(200);
}catch(e){
  console.log(`tahchelek lena ${e}`);
}
```

in the front-end i'm trying to display the image once i have an Image,
the  the code is  as follows , it's not working tho

```
import { InboxOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { message, Upload } from 'antd';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios  from  'axios';

const { Dragger } = Upload;



const App = () => {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(null);
  const handleUploadChange = async (info) => {
    const { status } = info.file;
    if (status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }
    if (status === 'done') {
      const response = info.file.response;
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
      
      setImageUrl(response.imageUrl); 
      return true; // notice i return true here in case it is uploaded succefully
    } else if (status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  };

  const handleFileDrop = (e) => {
    console.log('Dropped files', e.dataTransfer.files);
  };
```

i added the displayImage component so i can switch between it and dragger

```
  const DisplayImage = () => {
    const [imgPath, setImgPath] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('http://localhost:8000/getMap')
        .then((response) => response.blob())
        .then((blob) => {
          setImgPath(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error retrieving image:', error);
        });
    }, []);
    return (
      <div>
      {imgPath && <img src={imgPath} alt="Image uploaded"  />}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

from here on i'm facing the problem to change the view based on the handleUploadChange

```
  if(handleUploadChange===true){ 
    return(
      <DisplayImage />
    )
  }else{
  return (
    <div>
      <Dragger name="file" multiple={false} action="http://localhost:8000/upload" onChange={handleUploadChange} onDrop={handleFileDrop}>
        <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
          <InboxOutlined />
        </p>
        <p className="ant-upload-text">Click or drag file to this area to upload</p>
        <p className="ant-upload-hint">
          Support for a single or bulk upload. Strictly prohibited from uploading company data or other banned files.
        </p>
      </Dragger>
    </div>
  );
};
}
export default App;
```

I'm sorry if i couldnt explain the problem exactly as i should but i'm trying my best to understand every step.

Comment: Without going too deeply, once you execute `app.post('/upload', upload.single('file')...` you've modified Express's request routing and it will continue  to handle posts to `/upload` using the `upload.single("file")` middleware. It's not that I understand exactly what you want to do from the post, but I suspect the need is to use  directory empty detection each and every time an upload POST request is received.

Comment: i'm checking if directory empty so i can upload an image , if the directory is not empty i want to reject the user request for the upload

Comment: so you're saying that it doesnt matter the test? because once i request the /upload route from front it will execute? how can i preent executing the post ? thank you for your response

Comment: Check my answer for the first part of the question to see if it helps. If it does, I suggest cutting this question down to the first part,, and posting the second (React) part in another question - they are different areas of expertise and SO does not  wildly support multiple questions in one.

Answer (score 0):

**A Problem**

One problem is that telling Express to use middleware for a endpoint causes the express instance to add the endpoint and middleware references to its routing table. It doesn't matter that the adding was done in a condition statement (Express doesn't know that), so if you add it once, the endpoint is processed for future requests to the endpoint, whether or not the conditional passes.

The intent of the code in the `else` path of the conditional is unclear and probably doesn't do what you expected:

```
app.use('map', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'upload','heat-map')));
```

updates Express routing to run the static file server for GET requests to server endpoint `map` from a particular directory. However `express.static` does not handle POST requests and simply passes them through to the next routing check performed by express. If you want to turn the POST into a GET request you would need to set`req.method='GET'` update the `req.url` as needed, and deal with the consequences on the front end.

Adding clauses to express routing while processing a request is also problematic in that you can end up with multiple rules for the same endpoint. This clogs up the app unnecessarily - if a rule is processed once, routing never reaches duplicates of the rule, but if a rule fails, it processes every duplicate rule only to find they fail too.  I would expect the practice to generate a memory leak.

---

**Potential Solution**

To prevent multiple file uploads to `directoryPath`, try something like:

```js
let uploading = false;
app.post('/upload',
    (req, res, next) => {
        if(isDirectoryEmpty(directoryPath) && !uploading) {
            uploading = true;
            next();
            return;
        }
        let status = uploading ? 503 : 428;
        res.status(status).json({ message: 'No file uploaded' });  
    },
    upload.single('file'),
    (req, res) => {
        uploading = false;
        if (!req.file) {
            res.status(400).json({ message: 'No file uploaded' });
        }
        else{
            res.send("Image uploaded");
        }
    }
);
```